# scipy.optimize.fsolve fails for samples larger ~50 for a specific function, with different function parameter even earlier

Tags: python, scipy

I try to solve the equation

```
0 = -gamma + eta*(1-a*exp(gamma*t)*cos(omega*t))
```

numerically for gamma using [scipy.optimize.fsolve](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html#scipy.optimize.fsolve) for given omega, eta, a and t.
further is eta = .5*omega^2

this equation can be solved by WolframAlpha with the Lambert W-function, but I'll add more term and than there is no analytical solution anymore.

a simple exaple looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as opt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f(gamma, eta, omega, a):
    return -gamma + eta*(1-a*np.exp(gamma*60)*np.cos(omega*60))

omega_ = np.linspace(.001, .25, num=50)
eta_ = .5*omega_**2
gamma_ = opt.root(lambda gamma: f(gamma, eta_, omega_, .134)**2, eta_).x

plt.plot(omega_, gamma_/eta_ - 1)

plt.xlabel("omega")
plt.ylabel("gamma/eta - 1")
plt.show()
```

This Code generates this expected (correct) output: 
[image: expected and correct output]

while solving, a warning about a bad progress is usual and when I say, that the algorithm "fails", I mean that it returns the initial guess, which is in the plo just a straight line at y = gamma/eta -1 = 0

If I increase the number of datapoints, the solver fails. for the selected value of a=.134 it fails at ~55.

Further, if I change the value of a, the number of datapoints where it crashes changes. This is also a problem, because I want to fit via a in a later step.

I've tried to pass much more datapoints (up to 20000) to my function and it behaves fine and gives plausible results.
I've also tried the broyden1 algorithm and the optimize.root with the squared value in the lambda expression.

What's the Problem at this approach and how can the stability of the algorihm be increased?

EDIT:

by changing the gamma = ... line to

```
gamma_ = np.zeros(omega_.shape[0])
for i in range(omega_.shape[0]):
    gamma_[i] = opt.fsolve(lambda gamma: f(gamma, eta_[i], omega_[i], .134)**2, eta_[i])
```

it works for bigger problems... by not giving EVERY datapoint as a individual equation to solve

Comment: As the documentation you cite says: _fsolve is a wrapper around MINPACK’s hybrd and hybrj algorithms._ I am not sure if you have checked the documentation of those functions but this may give a clue how to increase the stability ([hybrd](https://www.math.utah.edu/software/minpack/minpack/hybrd.html) and [hybrj1](https://www.math.utah.edu/software/minpack/minpack/hybrj1.html) ).

Comment: ohh, it takes each row as individual equation... I've edited my post, which shows a (dirty) solution which iterates every point individually...

Comment: Try using brentq.